# como arrumar o resultado da tabuada para ficar no meio da pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

[como faço para o resultado da tabuada ficar no meio da pagina e não no canto, alguém pode me ajudar?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTY0a.jpg)

```
    <div class="tabuada">
        <h1>Tabuada MARVEL</h1>
    </div>

    <button class="botao__mostrar" onclick="mostrarTabuada()">Mostrar Tabuada</button>
    <button class="botao__limpar" onclick="limparTabuada()">Limpar Tabuada</button>
</div>
</header>

<script>

    var tabuada = document.querySelector(".tabuada");
    var mensagem = " ";
   
   function mostrarTabuada(){
     var n = prompt("Digite um número");
      n = parseFloat(n);

      var i = 1;

      while(i <= 10){
        mensagem += n + " x " + i + " = " + (n * i) + "<br>";

        i++;
      }

      tabuada.innerHTML = mensagem;
   }

      function limparTabuada(){
        mensagem = " ";
        tabuada.innerHTML = mensagem;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: No CSS faça `.tabuada{display: grid; place-items: center;}` Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Basic_concepts_of_grid_layout

Comment: Obrigadaa ,deu certo <3

Answer (score -2):

No arquivo css você pode tentar:

```
.tabuada{
   width: 100%;
   display:grid;
   place-items: center;
}
```

em casos de centralização e posicionamento, o mais facil e simples é usar ou grid ou flex, segue abaixo dois links de tutorias respectivamente

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Obrigadaa ,deu certo <3